# NavigationItem hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling not working from child view controller with table view inside of horizontal page controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

So I have the following layout:

```
UIViewController
  UISegmentControl
  UIPageViewControllerContainerUIView
    3 ViewControllers with table view inside as child view controllers for page controller
```

And I want to hide **search controller search bar** when user is swiping down the **inner** table view.

The UIPageViewController navigation is "horizontal" and transition needed is "scroll".

If I set page controller transition style to: page curl it works as the page controller does not use scroll view for transition between pages.

But I need to achieve the hiding of the search controller's search bar while having the horizontal scroll between pages.

I have tried everything but come close to what I need when setting the contentOffset.y of the page controller scroll view to the y offset of the current child view controller's inner table view but table view goes off screen.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.